# Converting string to keyword in clojure

Tags: clojure

Suppose i want to change a number in a loop to a keyword in order to check an entry in a dict/map:

```
(def myarray {:p1 "test"})
#'user/myarray
user> (get myarray 
           (keyword ":p1")
           )
nil
user> (get myarray 
           (symbol ":p1")
           )
nil
user>
```

I am just getting nil returned. What do i miss here?

Comment: You can use a number directly (without converting to a keyword) as a key in a map. `(get {1 "test"} 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

: is the indicator of keyword according to [the Clojure guide](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters), and the keyword function adds : automatically according to [the Clojure Docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keyword). So the correct code must be (keyword "p1") instead of (keyword ":p1").

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of how you can do it:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [m1 {:p1 "a"
            :p2 "b"}
        k1 (keyword (str "p" 1))
        k2 (keyword (str "p" 2))

        v1 (k1 m1)
        v2 (k2 m1)]
    (is= [k1 k2] [:p1 :p2])
    (is= [v1 v2] ["a" "b"])))
```

Note though, an integer is a perfectly valid map key:

```
(dotest
  (let [m1 {1 "a"
            2 "b"}
        k1 1
        k2 2

        v1 (get m1 k1) ; this doesn't work: (k1 m1 )
        v2 (get m1 k2)]
    (is= [k1 k2] [1 2])
    (is= [v1 v2] ["a" "b"])))
```

You just have to use the `get` function (with the map as 1st arg!).

The above code is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).